# Linq to Select a new object including a list

Tags: c#, linq

So I have the following

```
                UserData = (from r in results
                            from d in r.Details
                            from p in r.Payments
                            group d by new { r.id, r.Url, r.Name, p.Price, d }
                            into g
                            select new UserData
                            {
                                Id = g.Key.id,
                                Url = g.Key.Url,
                                Name = g.Key.Name,
                                Price = g.Key.Price
                                Details = g.key.d
                            }).ToList();
```

```
    public class UserData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        public List<Details> Details { get; set; }

    }
```

What I am trying to do is have a list of all the details, but it doesnt allow me to create a list inside the selected new object. Does anybody have any advice or know of how to do something similar? or where I am going wrong at all?

New to c# so anything on what I am doing would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to assign the list. What have you tried and what error are you getting?

Comment: So I have edited the doc. Where the Details is referred to, I cant seem to make that object a list. This will work if in the model I make the property just Details Details, but that wont work for me down the line. So I need some way of making it a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then the answer in Linq is

```
var details = list.Select(u => u.Details).ToList();
```

here the all code its run ok.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1  {
class Program
{

    public class UserData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        public List<Details> Details { get; set; }

    }
    public class Details
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //init the list 
        var list = new List<UserData>()
        {
                new UserData()//1
                {
                    id = "1",
                    Url = "some url 1",
                    Name = "name 1",Price = 0.1,
                    Details = new List<Details>(){
                        new Details()
                        {
                            id = "1",
                            Url = "some details url 1",
                            Name ="details name 1",
                            Price = 0.1
                        }
                    },
                },
                new UserData()//2
                {
                    id = "2",
                    Url = "some url 2",
                    Name = "name 2",Price = 0.2,
                    Details = new List<Details>(){
                        new Details()
                        {
                            id = "2",
                            Url = "some details url 2",
                            Name ="details name 2",
                            Price = 0.2
                        }
                    },
                }
        };

        //get only the details
        var details = list.Select(u => u.Details).ToList();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Superb! This has worked, my details model was a little different of course but it has worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

if you are working in ASP and want to list a database you can start here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Comment: No afraid im not working in ASP but thank you anyway